# How to create a user and group in chef without 'cloning resource' warning

Tags: chef-infra

I recently used following recipe to create a specific user, group:

```
sysadmin = data_bag_item('users','sysadmin')

group 'sysadmin' do
  action :create
  gid sysadmin['gid'].to_i
end

user 'sysadmin' do
  uid sysadmin['uid'].to_i
  gid sysadmin['gid'].to_i
  manage_home true
  shell sysadmin['shell']
  action :create
end

group 'sysadmin' do
  action :modify
  members 'sysadmin'
  append true
end
```

And get following warnings:

```
  Cloning resource attributes for group[sysadmin] from prior resource
Previous group[sysadmin]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/initialubuntu/recipes/sysadmin_user.rb:16:in `from_file'
Current  group[sysadmin]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/initialubuntu/recipes/sysadmin_user.rb:29:in `from_file' at 1 location:
```

Chef cannot create a user with gid of non-existent system group.

How to merge group resources into one?

Comment: Isn't it enough just to create the group and then add the user to it? Why are you calling the group again with :modify?

Comment: I do so. Chef user resource does not have group attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to rename one of them, for example you could rename the second one:

```
group 'append sysadmin' do
  group_name 'sysadmin'
  action :modify
  members 'sysadmin'
  append true
end
```

Alternatively if you upgrade to Chef 13, cloning has been removed at long last so these warnings are impossible now.